# Jolt json transformation to filter last 5 Hrs data

Tags: spring-boot, transformation, jolt

I am trying to filter the scenario that happened in last 5 hrs form the list of scenarios in spring boot application using jolt(jolt -core) json transfomer

```
Input Json:
[{
"scenarioId":120,
"scenarioTime":"2023-08-28 10:40:29 GMT"
},{
"scenarioId":121,
"scenearioTime":"2023-08-31 10:40:29 GMT"
}]

expected output:
[{
"scenarioId":121,
"scenarioTime":"2023-08-31 10:40:29 GMT"
}]


jolt Spec:
[{
  "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
  "spec": {
    "scenarioTime": "-toLong (@1, scenarioTime), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'"
    }
}]
```

I am new to jolt.Really appreciate your help